# Crystal report string display

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I was wondering if any can help me with this. I have created a string in the formula field of Crystal Report. However, the field isn't displaying as I want it to, at the moment it is displaying like this:

[image]

However, I want it to display like this instead:

[image]

Could someone please help me, I have tried Chr(9) and  Chr(10) and I can't seem to get the result

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing your formula syntax that will help us the exact wrong thing or add something. Also, you do not describe that all 3 separated value is in a single formula? if yes, then it will not work. You need to take 3 different formulas and do as below.

For "Carriage Return"(**or** enter **or** show string part in new line) use 'CHR(13)'

so your syntax will be (you may correct at your end)

1. Formula-1: `"Body " & CHR(13) & ": 9483 Turmeric Velvet"`
2. Formula-2: `"Small Scatters " & CHR(13) & ": 9093 Ochre Fragment"`
3. Formula-3: `"Feet " & CHR(13) & "Walnut Finish"`

Comment: Thank you for your response  this is the code I used: 
Body_heading + "" + Mid(Fld2, 3)+ " " + Fld1 + chr(13) +

Scatter_heading + "" + Fld4 + " " + Fld3 + chr(13) +

Feet_heading + "" + Mid(Fld6, 3)+ " " + Fld5 + chr(13)

Comment: so is this solved, if yes, then close the question by accepting the answer.